# has_many through: Why do I always need 2 associations for each of the 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-many-through

I wonder, why I always have to also specify the has_many :assignments association in both of the models in question **when using :through**? Is this DRY? Are there cases when I do not need to specify them, or when they differ? Thank you for explanation.

```
class Programmer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :through => :assignments
  has_many :assignments # Why that?
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programmers, :through => :assignments
  has_many :assignments # Why that?
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :programmer
end
```

**Update**

It seems I wasn't clear enough that I'm talking about **has_many :through**! So the answers given to this point don't really fit my question. So again:

**Why do I always need a `has_many :assignments` when I already have a `has_many :projects, :through => :assignments`?** Shouldn't Rails just add `has_many :assignments` itself automatically?

Comment: no, rails doesn't create the connection automatically. As I said on my answer, you need to understand the reason you cannot have a many-to-may relationship. The table between them (`assignments`) is solving the many-to-many problem. You can consider the `:through => :assignments` a favour rails is doing for you to facilitate things in your API.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still not getting why Rails doesn't do this (Pseudo Code):  `if has_many has :through parameter, then add has_many <value of through parameter> association`.

Comment: Doesn't matter which relationship definition you type in first in your class definition. At runtime, rails will look for the specification of that :through relationship. Rails is very good about simplifying your code through the use of conventions, but it doesn't make anything up on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is important to understand the below:

You have a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between `Programmer` and `Project`. In order to solve this relationship you have added a [junction model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) called `Assignment`.

Actually the table `projects` is not linked to the `programmers`, both are connected to `assignments` instead.

You could have something like this:

```
class Programmer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :programmer
end
```

However, you don't want to access the table `assignments` each time you want to find all projects related to a programmer. In order to facilitate this connection, you can create a direct link between `Programmer` and `Project`. So, you can say that `a programmer has many projects through the table assignments`.

The result is your current set up. Without this configuration you could not for example.

```
#find a programmer
@programmer = Programmer(1)  
#find all projects related to this programmer
@projects = @programmer.projects
```

On the above example you don't need to even remember that there is a table `assignments` between them.

Take a look here as well: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

I hope it helps...

**EDIT**

I have included a diagram, so you can visualise what I am trying to explain.

The `Project` and `Programmer` are not directly linked. So, `has_many :projects, :through => :assignments` is a Rails feature to facilitate thinks for you. And NO, it doesn't replace the `has_many :assignments`, which is the real connection to the table `assignments`.

Furthermore, the `:through =>` feature can be used in other circumstances as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice and detailed explanation. As written below, I was confused about this because Shoulda insists on both associations being present. I opened an issue on GitHub to ask the developer for the reason [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/129).

Comment: I have updated my question, it's about `has_many :through`, not only `has_many`! Maybe you can update your answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

The has many x through x line defines a relationship on its own. In your case it tells the Programmer model that a programmer has many projects and can find out about this relationship by looking at the assignment model. This doesn't specify a relationship with the assignment model in and of itself though. Hence why the second line is necessary.

Comment: This means, that I don't need the has_many association if I don't want to do stuff like `my_programmer.assignments`? But are there cases where I don't want this association to exist anyway? Wouldn't it be nicer to have it added automatically anyway?

Comment: Ok, after some research: According to [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/213#issuecomment-6874448), it absolutely **is** required! I tried it out myself, and yes, it doesn't work without both associations properly specified. So there's still the question: why doesn't Rails add the `has_many :xxx` (without `:through`) automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the assignments (and it has useful data on it) from both a programmer and a project instance, then yes, you have to include that association in each.

BUT, it's not required - so, if you don't need to access assignments and it's really just a join table, then leave it out.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But it's interesting that Shoulda matchers in RSpec insists on an existing `has_many` relationship, otherwise a spec like `it { should have_many(:userroles).through(:usergroup_userroles) }` doesn't pass. Is Shoulda wrong, or too much opinionated then?

Comment: According to [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/213#issuecomment-6874448), it absolutely **is** required! I tried it out myself, and yes, it doesn't work without both associations properly specified. So there's still the question: why doesn't Rails add the `has_many :xxx` (without `:through`) automatically?